# How do you Mockk a Kotlin top level function?

Tags: kotlin, mockk

[Mockk](https://mockk.io) allows mocking static functions, but how does one mock a Kotlin top level function?

For example, if I have a Kotlin file called `HelloWorld.kt`, how do I mock the `sayHello()` function?

---

**HelloWorld.kt**

```
fun sayHello() = "Hello Kotlin!"
```

Answer (score 62, accepted):

The following syntax has worked to me.

```kotlin
mockkStatic(::sayHello.javaMethod!!.declaringClass.kotlin)
```

I'm surprised there is nothing on the `jvm-stdlib` yet for this.

**Edit:**
This overload has now been introduced officially:
https://github.com/mockk/mockk/pull/518

```kotlin
mockkStatic(::sayHello)
```

Comment: This is definitely the best answer because it doesn't rely on hardcoded package path strings that can break if not refactored properly. This was the easiest approach that guarantees you're mocking the right method at compile time.

Comment: What about generic functions? this doesn't work.

Comment: This also doesn't work if there are multiple overloads

Comment: True. As far I know, this is a Kotlin limitation rather than MockK one.

Answer (score 36):

There is way to mockk a top level function:

```
mockkStatic("pkg.FileKt")
every { fun() } returns 5
```

You just need to know which file this function goes. Check in JAR or stack trace.

Comment: My question was too simplistic. Could the problem be that the top level function I'm trying to mock has a varargs parameter, but I'm doing `every { sayHello(any(), any(), any()) } returns "Hello Mockk!"` ?

Comment: My bad, there was something else that made _that_ fail.

Comment: Fill free to submit your problem to Gitter or GitHub issue with some piece of code. Stack Overflow is good for questions like you asked originally, but not for specific problems.

Comment: @oleksiyp is there something special I need to add to class file because I'm getting "Unresolved reference"  I tried building the project but I am not getting anything. I have the same structure as Niel. When I decompile the name is HelloWorldKt but I cannot find it in my tests

Comment: Should be nothing special. Just in case you didn't see it. https://blog.kotlin-academy.com/mocking-is-not-rocket-science-mockk-advanced-features-42277e5983b5

Comment: @oleksiyp thanks for quick response, my problem was I didn't wrap it in `"..."`

Comment: @oleksiyp, **How may I find the compiled Jar file with Android Studio?** I'm working to mock a top-level variable and need to find how Java compiles the Kotlin file into a class [as described](https://blog.kotlin-academy.com/mocking-is-not-rocket-science-mockk-advanced-features-42277e5983b5#6cb5) in your Medium series.

Answer (score 6):

To add on previous answers this is working:

```
mockkStatic("pkg.FileKt")
every { fun() } returns 5
```

Where mockStatic takes as an argument "package_name:class_file_name"
But to simplify the mockStatick call you can give your file a name for the compiler with @file:JvmName directly in the file.

HelloWorld.kt

```
@file:JvmName("hello")
fun sayHello() = "Hello Kotlin!"
```

HelloWorldTest.kt

```
mockkStatic("pkg.hello")
every { fun() } returns 5
```

More detailed explication on why this is necessary and other examples here:https://blog.kotlin-academy.com/mocking-is-not-rocket-science-mockk-advanced-features-42277e5983b5

Answer (score 1):

Building on @Sergey's answer:

You could have the actual implementation of the `sayHello()` function in a variable that's then the default value of a function parameter to `sayHello()`.

This example works:

```
package tests

import io.mockk.every
import io.mockk.mockk
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test

val sayHelloKotlin = { "Hello Kotlin!" }
fun sayHello(producer: () -> String = sayHelloKotlin): String = producer()

class Tests {
    interface Producer {
        fun produce(): String
    }

    @Test
    fun `Top level mocking`() {
        val mock = mockk<Producer>()
        every { mock.produce() } returns "Hello Mockk"

        val actual = sayHello(mock::produce)
        Assertions.assertEquals(actual, "Hello Mockk")
    }
}
```

The problem with this is that you're changing production code just to cater for testing, and it feels contrived.

Comment: Right. You can try the second approach I've described. It allows you not to change production code.

Answer (score 1):

This code doesn't work for me with mockk version 1.10.0 but works well in 1.11.0 (of course need to change mockkStatic(::bar) )

Utils.kt

```kotlin
@file:JvmName("UtilsKt")
package com.example.myapplication

fun foo(): Boolean {
  return bar()
}

fun bar():Boolean {
  return false
}
```

Test

```kotlin
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner::class)
@Config(sdk = [Build.VERSION_CODES.O_MR1])
class ExampleUnitTest {
    @Test
    fun addition_isCorrect() {
        mockkStatic("com.example.myapplication.UtilsKt")
        every { bar() } returns true
        assertTrue(foo())
    }
}
```